# UART for MSP430FR5969

Tags: c, embedded, uart, msp430

I'm new for using **MSP430FR5969**.

I want to program my uart1 to connect the bluetooth **PAN1026** with my **MSP430**.

at the begining I send a rest mode `{ 0x01, 0x03,0x0c,0x00 }` and the bluetooth must answer me
`{ 0x04,0x0e,0x04,0x04,0x03,0x0c,0x00 }`

So I want to put a condition on `UCA1RXBUF` it must be equal to `{ 0x04,0x0e,0x04,0x04,0x03,0x0c,0x00 }` until I pass to the second step

else I redo the first step.

Here is my code.

```
    #include "usart.h"
    void USART0_Init (void) {   // Controller -> PC
    P2SEL1 |= BIT0| BIT1;                    // Configure UART pins
      P2SEL0 &= ~(BIT0| BIT1);

      // Disable the GPIO power-on default high-impedance mode to activate
      // previously configured port settings
      PM5CTL0 &= ~LOCKLPM5;

      // Startup clock system with max DCO setting ~8MHz
      CSCTL0_H = CSKEY >> 8;                    // Unlock clock registers
      CSCTL1 = DCOFSEL_3 | DCORSEL;             // Set DCO to 8MHz
      CSCTL2 = SELA__VLOCLK | SELS__DCOCLK | SELM__DCOCLK;
      CSCTL3 = DIVA__1 | DIVS__1 | DIVM__1;     // Set all dividers
      CSCTL0_H = 0  ;                           // Lock CS registers

      // Configure USCI_A1 for UART mode
      UCA0CTLW0 = UCSWRST;                      // Put eUSCI in reset
      UCA0CTLW0 |= UCSSEL__SMCLK;               // CLK = SMCLK
      UCA0BR0 = 4;     //4;                             // 8000000/16/115200
      UCA0BR1 = 0x00;
      UCA0MCTLW |= 0x55;                         //UCOS16 | UCBRF_1;
      UCA0CTLW0 &= ~UCSWRST;                    // Initialize eUSCI
     // UCA0IE |= UCRXIE;                         // Enable USCI_A0 RX interrupt

}
void USART1_Init (void) {   // Controller <-> PAN1026

    P2SEL1 |= BIT5| BIT6;                    // Configure UART pins
      P2SEL0 &= ~(BIT5| BIT6);

      // Configure USCI_A1 for UART mode
      UCA1CTLW0 = UCSWRST;                      // Put eUSCI in reset
      UCA1CTLW0 |= UCSSEL__SMCLK;               // CLK = SMCLK
      UCA1BR0 = 4;                             // 8000000/16/115200
      UCA1BR1 = 0x00;
      UCA1MCTLW |=0x55; //UCOS16 | UCBRF_1;
      UCA1CTLW0 &= ~UCSWRST;                    // Initialize eUSCI
     // UCA1IE |= UCRXIE;                         // Enable USCI_A0 RX interrupt
}
void USART0_SendByte (unsigned char data) {
    while(!(UCA0IFG & UCTXIFG));
    UCA0TXBUF = data;
}
void USART1_SendByte (unsigned char data) {
    while(!(UCA1IFG & UCTXIFG));
    UCA1TXBUF = data;
}
void USART0_SendData (unsigned char data[], unsigned char length) {
    unsigned char i;

    for(i=0; i<length; i++) {
        USART0_SendByte(data[i]);
    }
}
void USART1_SendData (unsigned char data[], unsigned char length) {

    unsigned char i;

    for(i=0; i<length; i++) {
        USART1_SendByte(data[i]);
    }
}
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#include <msp430.h>
// Header files
#include "usart.h"

unsigned char TCU_HCI_RESET_REQ[4] = {0x01, 0x03, 0x0c, 0x00};

void main(void) {

        WDT_A_hold(WDT_A_BASE);

    USART0_Init();
    USART1_Init();
while(1){
    USART0_SendData(TCU_HCI_RESET_REQ,4);
    USART1_SendData(TCU_HCI_RESET_REQ,4);
    __delay_cycles(150000);
}
}
```

Comment: Ok, so what's your question?

Comment: You'll need to write the UART input routines too, with a timeout. Make it `int USART0_ReadByte(void)` so that it can return `-1` on timeout.

Comment: Note: do not use the built-in type names, but use `stdint.h` types. `uint8_t`, etc. Note also, there is littel gain in using `char` or 8 bit types where not needed (e.g. counters), as the MSP430 is a 16 bit CPU and all operations are done as 16 bits anyway (except for load/store which also allow for 8 bits).

Answer (score 1):

you need to write `UART` receive `ISR` routine and store data coming from `PAN1026`. Then after coming out of `ISR` you can check for data from Bluetooth and take respective decision.

Comment: I would not recommend implementing an `ISR` until the polled version is working. Step by step.

Comment: @WeatherVane: I agree if there is no other functionality except receiving data

Comment: Step 1: establish the handshake. So much easier to debug inline code than an `ISR`.